# How to use relative url in jquery.getJSON method to have access data in a server?

Tags: jquery, json, github-pages

I use this code in my project to get data from a json file:

`$.getJSON("../data/01_test.json", function (json) { showData(json); });`

It was Ok in local host But when i deploye my project in github-pages, it dose not find this file. And i get this error:

> *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*

I just used html, css, javascript, jquery and bootsrap in this project.

So I want when i deploy it, can read this file and show data and fix this error.

---

Can anyone guide me how to solve this problem?
Is the problem because of the getJson method or not?

Comment: Hi Fzh, welcome. We need more details about how you're bundling your static site. Can you provide more context to your problem?